# Empty 'SPONSORED BY' label under top bar - AWS logo not shown

Tags: support, design, site-sponsorship

When viewing this site (main or meta) in my main browser, there is an empty 'SPONSORED BY' label just under the top bar:

[image]
[image]

When viewing in another browser, the AWS logo is showing correctly:

[image]

Comment: I can see it is sponsored by AWS machine learning tho..

Comment: @ClementHui thanks, it seems browser-related.

Comment: Oh I see thanks.

Comment: @Glorfindel I am using Chrome and I am not seeing the AWS logo.

Comment: Are you using adblocker? I'm using uBlock Origin and it catches the sponsorship logo but not the "Sponsored by"... which is interesting because it doesn't catch the logo on Quantum Computing.

Comment: @Catija thanks, that's exactly what's causing this; see the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Catija's hunch](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1636/empty-sponsored-by-label-under-top-bar-aws-logo-not-shown#comment3208_1636) was right: the logo is blocked by uBlock, since it's a link to ad.doubleclick.net.

I *would* have checked that, if I hadn't seen the AWS logo on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) a few weeks ago. But right now it's not showing there either. I guess the ad link is important enough (in terms of revenue, or just part of the sponsorship contract) to keep it, so I'm no longer considering it a [bug](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug).

Comment: Yeah, so I talked with the ads team. Apparently AWS wants to track link clicks, which goes through a tool that causes the ad blockers read the image as an ad. Apparently the one on QC doesn't have that, so it doesn't get blocked. :)