# Are we still sponsored by AWS?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-sponsorship

After [Empty 'SPONSORED BY' label under top bar - AWS logo not shown](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1636/2444), the "sponsored by" has completely disappeared from the site. Are we still sponsored by AWS or anyone?

Answer (score 3):

The "sponsored by" is gone, for now, because the site sponsorship is currently paused.

While we don't have a set date yet for the sponsorship to return, current conversations with AWS point to relaunching in early Q3, though the date isn't locked in yet.

Comment: Does the sponsorship provide any intellectual contribution or is it just monetary contribution alone?

Comment: @DuttaA while we're certainly open for people from those companies participating and would encourage it, that's not mandatorily part of the deal. By contract, site sponsorships are monetary contributions.

Comment: How much money does a company need to provide, to be a sponsor?

Answer (score 2):

Seems AWS came back up in the "Sponsored by" section recently, this is what it looks like right now:

[image]